# How do I stop a macOS upgrade while it's already in progress?

Tags: big-sur, auto-update

I just rebooted my Mac to find it's now upgrading to Big Sur. I found out that if I hard power off the Mac, it will still work next time, but will begin the update process again.

How can I stop the process and go back to Mojave?

Comment: Is the updater in the Applications folder?  If so, I think you can just delete it.

Comment: How? Do I boot in some special mode?

Comment: I thought you meant you just got the update pop-up so I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I'd want to know how it even started an **upgrade**, not update, without the specific action of an admin account.

Comment: I probably clicked something half-brained in the past weeks (i almost never reboot).. damn popups..

Comment: Don't think you have much options other than to let it install. Powering it off mid-way through may corrupt the system, so don't do that. You can always downgrade back to Mojave, but requires you to go to the original operating system your Mac was shipped with and then upgrading to Mojave.